# How do I add the image orientation exif metadata information on an image saved on the camera roll?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

After post-producing the pictures taken with the iphone camera and saving them to the camera roll, I see the final result is being saved without the orientation information.

When the iPhone reads these pictures, it reads orientation = "0", that is "taken with the iphone button on the right", and that messes all up.

How do I save the orientation metadata on the picture going to the camera roll?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the only way was to render processed image in a correct orientation yourself and then save it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the file format:

If you save with UIImageJPEGRepresentation() the orientation is saved correctly in the exif data. If you load a JPEG file with exif orientation data you get an UIImage with a it's imageOrientation set and the original CGImage data(unrotated).

If you save with UIImagePNGRepresentation() it doesn't save the orientation in the exif data(or anywhere). If you load a png with exif orientation data then it prerotates the CGImage data and always gives you a UIImage with an imageOrientation of "UIImageOrientationUp".

I figured this out from various posts and experimentation.

So displaying either PNG or JPEG UIImages works the same, but messing with the data is very different.